# Git push from fork to specific remote branch?

Tags: git, github

Still a git noobie, been using very basic commands to commit, push, pull.

I am taking a forked project and pushing it to a private repo, I do this by creating a remote within the forked repo

```
git remote add mysite https://github.com/Siterepo/site.git
```

Then upon changes I push it to my private repo.

```
git push -u mysite master
```

---

My question is first is this even logical, should I just skip using a forked version since this is google web starter kit and there are some brilliant guys who most likely wont need my contributions.

So I should just clone the web starter kit into my own repo then customize at will? Will I still be able to merge updates this way if so how?

---

Okay so suppose I should follow what I said above then this is useless, but in case the logic I initially came up with GoogleMaster > MyFork > MyMaster how do I push to a specific branch, I said I used

```
git push -u mysite master
```

But

```
git push -u mysite testBranch
```

Does not work.

The reason I want my own repo is so that I can push my own versions, have my own branches and somewhat abstract from the initial project while still being able to merge when they make some drastic or better performance etc updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is first is this even logical, should I just skip using a forked version since this is google web starter kit and there are some brilliant guys who most likely wont need my contributions.

you don't have to fork (clone on the server) if you don't plan to contribute back.
You can simply clone it, then change the remote named 'origin' url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Siterepo/site.git
```

And you can start pushing to your private repo.

> Will I still be able to merge updates this way if so how?

You still can add a second remote, referencing the original repo, if you want to keep an eye on it:

```
git remote add upstream /url/of/first/repo
```

---

This should work:

```
git push -u mysite master:testBranch
```

or:

```
git checkout -b testBranch
git push -u mysite testBranch
```

Comment: Yeah thanks that's kind of what I thought, it's great to get some feedback and a reference. I'll green check this once I set it up just to make it official. Thanks

Comment: BTW did you mean +`git remote add upstream /url/of/first/repo` great answer... admiring that 438k rep